# Unable to connect to server using ftp_connect

Tags: php, unix, ftp

I've tried just about everything, but unable to form a connection using `ftp_connect`. There is no error message, so I don't know where to look. It just times-out.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$remote_file = 'file.txt'; 

$ftp_host = '1.1.1.1';
$ftp_user_name = 'root@1.1.1.1';
$ftp_user_pass = 'password'; 

$local_file = 'file.txt';

$connect_it = ftp_connect($ftp_host) or die("Could not connect");

$login_result = ftp_login($connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    echo "WOOT! Successfully transfer $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close( $connect_it );
?>
```

Both servers are mine so I know they are both on and working. The server is trying to connect and unless I set up a time out it just keeps going and going but the connection is not made. All I'm trying to do is transfer one text file from one VPS to another.

Comment: ok, and the error is?

Comment: What message do you get on failure? Have you tried using another ftp client to confirm that the server is responding?

Comment: Both servers are mine so I know they are both on and working. There is no error message. The server is trying to connect and unless I set up a time out it just keeps going and going but the connection is not made. All I'm trying to do is transfer one text file from one VPS to another.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection simply times out without error, this means there is a port that isn't opened on one server or the other.

Here is what you could try:

1. maybe turn error reporting on:

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
   ```
2. check on both servers that the port you intend to use is opened

   ```
   $ netstat -a|grep ftp
   tcp        0      0 *:ftp                       *:*                         LISTEN
   ```

   (here you try to use the default that should be "21")
3. check that you're able to telnet the thing

   ```
   telnet <host> <port>
   ```
4. Then try just the minimal ftp connect

   ```
   $ftp_host='1.1.1.1';
   $ftp_user_name = 'root'; // I think in your case you should not add '@1.1.1.1'...
   $ftp_user_pass = 'password'; 
   $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_host) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_host"); 
   // Then chdir to a directory:
   ftp_chdir($conn_id, "/your/dir");
   $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
   ```
5. See the [full documentation of PHP's FTP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/book.ftp.php).

Comment: Still not able to make it work. tried port 21 and 22. FTP does not connect.